# Upgrading timescaledb from 2.3.0 to 2.6.0

Tags: timescaledb

I have timescaledb 2.3.0 and PostgreSQL 13.5 installed in my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to upgrade to timescale 2.6.0.

When giving the following command in postgreSQL:

```
ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;
```

I get the following message:

```
extension "timescaledb" has no update path from version "2.3.0" to version "2.4.0"
```

Any hint how I should proceed?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you don't need to be explicit about the latest version. See the [docs](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/update-timescaledb/#update-timescaledb).

> This upgrades TimescaleDB to the latest installed version, even if you're several versions behind. To update to a version that's not the latest installed version, specify the version number, like this:

```sql
ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE TO '2.6.0';
```

Have you tried to update to `2.4` first?

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue by removing Timescale and doing a new installation.